does arduino uses standard (real) c++ code at the end?
I think Arduino language is C++ with combination of Arduino libraries for example in this code :
int ledPin = 13;  // LED connected to digital pin 13
int inPin = 7;    // pushbutton connected to digital pin 7
int val = 0;      // variable to store the read value

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // sets the digital pin 13 as output
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);    // sets the digital pin 7 as input
}

void loop() {
  val = digitalRead(inPin);   // read the input pin
  digitalWrite(ledPin, val);  // sets the LED to the button's value
}

as you can to see the code have Arduino Specific Functions like pinMode, digitalWrite, digitalRead  that likely reside in the Arduino C++ libraries
I know that compiling this code with avr-gcc directly would result in errors. However, Arduino uses avr-gcc internally (as evident from the compilation errors in the Arduino IDE) also I think avr-gcc only supports standard (real) C++ . So, if Arduino code is what I described, shouldn't I be able to compile it directly using avr-gcc from the terminal by providing the Arduino libraries, or at least be able to access an avr-gcc compatible code that Arduino generates before sending it for compilation?

It is real C++. The Arduino specific functions are not language features, but come from "Arduino.h". The compiler just implicitly include "Arduino.h" for .ino file. If you call pinMode or digitalWrite in a .cpp file, you have to #include "Arduino.h" otherwise it won't compile.
